# Investigating Failures of a Subreport in SSRS 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2016

I have a SSRS report, MainReport, that basically just calls a series of sub-reports to compile everything into a nice and tidy Excel Document (users love their Excel reports), with each sub-report occupying its own tab.  On occasion, one of the sub-reports, Subreport1, will fail displaying *Error: Subreport could not be shown* within the Excel tab and nothing else.  Digging through the [various SSRS server and execution logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/reporting-services-log-files-and-sources?view=sql-server-2017), I'm able to identify that the sub-report in question encountered an error, but the error description is not exactly useful:

```
reportrendering!WindowsService_1!1cb4!06/07/2018-01:55:13:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RenderingObjectModelException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RenderingObjectModelException: Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'Subreport1', located at: /Folder/Subreport1. Please check the log files for more information. ;
processing!WindowsService_1!1cb4!06/07/2018-01:55:13:: e ERROR: An error has occurred while processing a sub-report. Details: Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'Subreport1', located at: /Folder/Subreport1. Please check the log files for more information.  Stack trace:
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.SubReport.FinalizeErrorMessageAndThrow()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.SubReport.RetrieveSubreport()
```

**I'm trying to figure out what the explicit error code in question is**, and so far my efforts to do so have resulted in dead ends.

When reviewing the [ExecutionLog3 view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-executionlog-and-the-executionlog3-view?view=sql-server-2017) for the main report, it shows that it renders without issue:

```
ItemPath            RequestType     TimeStart               TimeEnd                 Format          Status
/Folder/MainReport  Subscription    2018-06-07 01:25:02.397 2018-06-07 01:55:13.537 EXCELOPENXML    rsSuccess
```

I would have expected to see an error code pop for the main report, but because it technically *did render*, I guess I can understand why a Success is being reported.

When I look for the execution record of the sub-report, there isn't a correlating run-time listed that matches up with the run-time of the main report.  The logged executions of the sub-report are no where near the rendering period of the main report, so I suspect SSRS is not logging each sub-report execution individually.  Here's all the available records that exist in my logs for the sub-report around the execution time of the main report:

```
ItemPath            RequestType TimeStart               TimeEnd                 Format          Status
/Folder/SubReport1  Interactive 2018-06-07 08:04:23.010 2018-06-07 08:08:14.540 RPL             rsProcessingAborted
/Folder/SubReport1  Interactive 2018-06-05 09:39:38.620 2018-06-05 09:39:39.557 EXCELOPENXML    rsSuccess
```

I know in this particular example I can infer that the sub-report exceeded the default timeout threshold of 30 minutes, but again, I cannot locate the explicit error that tells me so.  So my question is quite simply, is there another log or location I've not come across that would show more details pertaining to the error(s) of the sub-report, or are these just not captured?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out on your own? I'm running into the same problem, those subreports are SO touchy, they fail more often than they succeed. Thanks

Comment: @JustSomeGuy Sadly not. We’ve basically kept the number of these types of reports rather limited, so when an error does occur we can generally trace it back to a change we made.  I can’t imagine the headache of having to support a large number of these.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener I am in your shoes now and finding unanswered threads like this everywhere. Looks like no one knows if SSRS even logs the sub-report errors. I have many reports that are 'Report books' made out of dynamically generated number of subreports (e.g. one sub report per country). Now one of them fails randomly, and these aren't really huge reports like yours. Business asks 'why is this failing' and I have nothing to show for it. Any chance you figured something out in last few months? :) (edit: sorry for the rant)

Comment: @SudarshanKadam, no formal solution has been found.  What I would suggest for you is to break out the report and subreports into their individual components and run it using the parameters/timings/etc. you are running the consolidated report with while it generates an error(s).  Hopefully the broken out reports will then produce the error code necessary to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying @JohnEisbrener My situation is even funnier. The said report is Sub-report of a sub-report (don't ask smh :D) and is being executed as a data driven subscription every weekend. User says it doesn't always fail on the same page (i.e. same sub report) but it's random. Now I think it might be something to do with processing thousands of subscriptions creating bottlenecks/timeouts. Tracking this error is going to drive me nuts. Oh and btw it NEVER fails when we run the report manually with same parameters. :)

Comment: @SudarshanKadam We've seen timeouts occur when a flood of subscriptions all fire at the same time as well, so if that's what's causing your issues, that's another basket of headaches to deal with.  If you ever find a SSRS grief support group, let me know as I'd gladly join just to laugh at our collective misery.  Good luck!